# Fit background image of an outer div based on inner div size

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to make my background image of the site container div automatically fit based on the inner div.

[image]

See the image. The middle girl image is within a container. There is a curtain in the background. I want to fit the curtain background to the left and the right of the image container div, so there is no gap between.

```
.site_holder {
    position: relative;
    background: url(images/slider_bg.png);
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

<div class="new_slide">
  <div class="new_slide_pic">
    <img src="your image url" alt="">  
  </div>
```

Comment: use background-size: cover;

Comment: Although not technically a code solution, I think it would be easier to put all three images in photoshop, and make the image one big image, as opposed to three smaller ones. If you want us to solve as an HTML problem, you're gonna have to provide us the code in a JSFiddle.